# Compare objects and search in list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyside2

I use Python 3 and PySide2 (Qt for Python) (both up to date). I have a list of PySide2 objects and have to check if an item exists in the list. If I try to do this, I get the error:

```py
NotImplementedError: operator not implemented.
```

```py
from PySide2 import QtGui
item = QtGui.QStandardItem()
item1 = QtGui.QStandardItem()

item == item1 # creates error

list1 = [item, item1]
item1 in list1 # creats error
```

What do I wrong? How can I do this? Do I have to implement the "==" operator myself?
Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: That is an old bug that still persists in PySide2: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-74 , You talk about comparing and searching, but in a QStandardItem that you want to compare: the text, the background color, some role in specific ?, if so, there are other methods. Besides the QStandardItem that they show does not belong to any model, I think you have a [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377)

Comment: Thank you @eyllanesc for your help. The link to the XY problem was very interesting. I think you're right, i have to rethink my Problem. Only for clarification: I have a subclass of QStandardItem. This class is an observer of a model class. The model class has a register-method to add an observer to a list of obersevers. And during the register-method I want to check if the observer is alredy registered. And here I have to search in the list where I get the error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted in a comment, the error you get is part of a [bug](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-74) that is remnants of PySide.

I think that you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377), and what you want is to check if there is an item with a predefined text. If so, it is not necessary to implement the operator `==` but use the [findItems()](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qstandarditemmodel.html#findItems) method:

```
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    md = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for text in ("Hello", "Stack", "Overflow"):
        md.appendRow(QtGui.QStandardItem(text))

    words = ("Hello", "World")

    for word in words:
        if md.findItems(word, flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly, column=0):
            print(f"{word} exists")
        else:
            print(f"{word} not exists")
```

Or use the [match()](https://doc.qt.io/Qt-5/qabstractitemmodel.html#match) method if you want to search for some other role:

```py
from PySide2 import QtCore, QtGui

FooRole = QtCore.Qt.UserRole + 1000

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys

    md = QtGui.QStandardItemModel()
    for i, text in enumerate(("Hello", "Stack", "Overflow")):
        it = QtGui.QStandardItem(str(i))
        it.setData(text, FooRole)
        md.appendRow(it)

    words = ("Hello", "World")

    for word in words:
        if md.match(
            md.index(0, 0), FooRole, word, hits=1, flags=QtCore.Qt.MatchExactly
        ):
            print(f"{word} exists")
        else:
            print(f"{word} not exists")
```

Comment: Awesome. Thank you very much @eyllanesc. Ít works perfect for me!

Answer (score 0):

The operator `==` is equivalent with `__eq__`. The usage is like `a.__eq__(b)` or `a == b`. And the exception is saying [the class](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython/PySide2/QtGui/QStandardItem.html) has no implementation of that method.

And the doc does say:

> Reimplement operator if you want to control the semantics of item comparison. operator determines the sorted order when sorting items with `sortChildren()` or with `sort()`.

Comment: You are using an obsolete docs, PySide is not PySide2. PySide is deprecated.

Comment: Thank you to knh190 and eyllanesc for the suggestions and help.
I have to rethink my concrete problem. Perhaps the reimplementation of __eq__ is the solution. Thank you!