# How to use for <item> in <list> with QTreeWidget

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyside2

I have a list of QTreeWidgetItem objects and I'm getting a NotImplementedError when I use for `<item>` in `<list>` test. Does anyone know what I have to implement on the QTreeWidgetItem to get that working? I tried overloading the hash operator but that didn't fix it - I get the same error.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
_list = [QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem() for _idx in range(3)]
print _list[1] in _list
```

This is the error message:

```
# Error: operator not implemented.
# Traceback (most recent call last):
#   File "<maya console>", line 2, in <module>
# NotImplementedError: operator not implemented. #
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Compare objects and search in list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56323661/compare-objects-and-search-in-list)

Comment: As noted in the duplicate answer: it is a pyside2 bug, but in general it is not necessary, if you are looking for a specific item then you must use the [findItems](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtreewidget.html#findItems) method from QTreeWidget

Comment: hmm that doesn't really work for me, i need to find if the item triggering a callback is currently selected - but now i know that's a bug i can find a workaround, i can just use QTreeWidgetItem.isSelected. thanks for the info :)

Comment: As you realize, you have an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), your question should have been: How to know if an item was selected? and for this it is not necessary to use the "in" operator.

Comment: not really - i know how to find if an item is selected. it was useful for me to ask this question to understand why my code wasn't working; i should have been able to use my solution if there wasn't that bug in PySide2.

Answer (score 0):

Like it's mentioned in the comments it's a bug. Here's a workaround using `id()` that you may be able to use instead:

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets


_list = [QtWidgets.QTreeWidgetItem() for _idx in range(3)]
removed_item = _list.pop(1)
_ids = [id(item) for item in _list]
print id(removed_item) in (_ids)  # Returns False
```